# Refresh menu not updating the content

Tags: android, android-menu

I was doing udacity course on android app development.I have created a refresh menu button for the weather app, but the data is not at all updating when i click refresh menu.
Here is the code (please ignore arrayadapter)

```html
package app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
* A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
*/
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment
{

public ForecastFragment() {
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] forecastArray = {
        "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
        "Tomarrow - Foggy - 70/40",
        "Wed - Sunny - 88/63",
        "Thurs - Sunny - 88/63",
        "Fri - Sunny - 88/63",
        "Sat - Sunny - 88/63",
        "Sun - Sunny - 88/63"};

List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
            weekForecast
   );

    // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
    // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
    String forecastJsonStr = null;
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=1261481&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In your AsyncTask you fetch the data json and that's about it. You don't parse it to extract the required data and set it on the adapter so nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data which you have fetched as json in `forecastJsonStr` . You haven't used this fetched string anywhere . Override `onPostExecute()` method of asynctask class which will receive as parameter returned by `doInBackground()` method . then parse this(`forecastJsonStr`) json string and set values where you want . I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.I added these lines to get it working

```html
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result != null) {
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
                // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
            }
        }
```